# Парсер plist для android. Четкий пример, как получить данные

Tags: java, android, xml, парсер

У меня есть Plist вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
  <key>applicationContent</key>
   <array>
    <dict>
       <key>stringIDKey</key>
           <string>1</string>
       <key>titleKey</key>
           <string>Название</string>
       <key>previewImageServerPathKey</key>
           <string>http://example.com/image.png</string>
       <key>version</key>
           <string></string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
       <key>stringIDKey</key>
           <string>2</string>
       <key>titleKey</key>
           <string>Название2</string>
       <key>previewImageServerPathKey</key>
           <string>http://example.com/image2.png</string>
       <key>version</key>
           <string></string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
       <key>stringIDKey</key>
           <string>3</string>
       <key>titleKey</key>
           <string>Название3</string>
       <key>previewImageServerPathKey</key>
           <string>http://example.com/image3.png</string>
       <key>version</key>
           <string></string>
    </dict>
   </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Очень много читал про разные парсеры, но так и не получилось получить данные из моего plist 
Подскажите на четком примере для моего plist, как правильно его распарсить и как воспользоваться данными (хотя бы вывести в textview все данные). Нужон конкретный код, спасибо.

Данные читаю из файла

```
FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("previewdata.plist");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[fin.available()];
    fin.read(bytes);
    String textdata = new String (bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот ответ!

```
public class XmlMapParser extends Application {
private XmlPullParser parser;
public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

public void setMap(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map) {
    this.map = map;
}

public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> getMap() {
    return map;
}

public void convert(String nameFile) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    //HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    XmlPullParserFactory parserFactory;
    parserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    parserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    parser = parserFactory.newPullParser();
    parser.setInput(new StringReader(nameFile));
    final String KEY = "key", STRING = "string";

    try {
        parser.next();
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        String lastTag = null;
        String lastKey = null;

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                lastTag = parser.getName();
            }
            else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                // some text
                if (KEY.equalsIgnoreCase(lastTag)) {
                    // start tracking a new key
                    lastKey = parser.getText();
                }
                else if (STRING.equalsIgnoreCase(lastTag)) {
                    // a new string for the last encountered key
                    if (!map.containsKey(lastKey)) {
                        map.put(lastKey, new ArrayList<String>());
                    }

                    map.get(lastKey).add(parser.getText());
                }
            }

            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setMap(map);
}
}
```

Данные запишутся в hashmap и вы сможете получить их по нужному вам ключу.

Вот пример использования:

```
XmlMapParser mapParser = new XmlMapParser();
try {
        mapParser.convert(finalData);
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mapone = mapParser.getMap();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```